# IxLoad icConfigError: Cannot mix legacy and new-style network objects in a single script

Tags: tcl

I am using Ixload 5.10 Version and TCL 8.4.14.

I do not have help support, so hopefully someone could help me out with this. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

This is my code. Once I add ixNet....Plugin, TCL log file will show the error "Lib.Comon.ixConfig.ixConfigError:Cannot mix legacy and new-style  network objects in a single script..."

I don't know if there is any other package that I need to load or not? In my code, I have initialized these already.

```
package require statCollectorUtils
global ixAppPluginManager
$ixAppPluginManager load "HTTP"


set clnt_network [::IxLoad new ixNetworkGroup $chassisChain]
    $clnt_network config \
    -name "clnt_network"
$clnt_network globalPlugins.clear

set Filter [::IxLoad new ixNetFilterPlugin]
# ixNet objects needs to be added in the list before they are configured!
$clnt_network globalPlugins.appendItem -object $Filter\
$Filter config \
    -name "Filter"

set GratArp [::IxLoad new ixNetGratArpPlugin]
# ixNet objects needs to be added in the list before they are configured!
$clnt_network globalPlugins.appendItem -object $GratArp
$GratArp config \
    -enabled true \
    -name "GratArp"

set TCP [::IxLoad new ixNetTCPPlugin]
# ixNet objects needs to be added in the list before they are configured!
$clnt_network globalPlugins.appendItem -object $TCP
$TCP config \
    -tcp_tw_recycle true \
    -tcp_keepalive_time 75 \
    -tcp_keepalive_intvl 7200 \
    -tcp_wmem_default 4096 \
    -tcp_port_min 1024 \
    -tcp_port_max 65535 \
    -tcp_window_scaling false \
    -name "TCP" \
    -tcp_rmem_default 4096
```

Comment: This is the example in IxloadTclApi.pdf

Comment: This is not a Tcl problem but rather an application problem. (Tcl itself knows nothing about “network objects”; I'm guessing that's part of Ixload…)

Comment: I have read a few times the doc IxLoadTclApi, and also copied all the examples in the DOC, however, I got the same error as well, so how can IXIA give me the example that TCL itself doesn't know the network objects? Just really got frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I looked into IxLoad today and Found that there is a tool called ScriptGen on Ixload, which can generate the configurations to a TCL script file. It makes my life so much easy.